# In Laravel 4 - SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I get this error in Laravel 4. My config/database.php file says,

```
'connections' => array(

    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
        'database'  => 'my-site-name',
        'username'  => 'my-site-name',
        'password'  => 'my-password',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

Earlier I changed my environment to production, then now to local.

Comment: What comes up in the breadcrumbs at the top of the navigation when you go into phpmyadmin? Is your username/password combination correct? The more information the better.

Comment: I believe it's correct and I'll double check. But should the error say the user is "forge"?

Comment: Actually check out @emartal's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you changed your environment to `local`, you should check if you have a `database.php` file located in your `\app\config\local\` folder.  Your environment specific configurations override the global ones from your `\app\config\` folder.

Seeing as your connection is trying to use the `forge` username for `localhost`, it seems like the configuration you just posted is being overwritten by another config file.

Comment: Oh, I get how it works now. Checking the file in config/local shows the right info, though. Which is weird because I never edited it. I Artisan moves it?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, is it possible you got your `Laravel` installation from a source that already had a `local` configuration file?

Comment: I used the laravel installer (laravel.phar), so I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

In database.php

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'your_db_name'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'your_db_user_name'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'your_db_password'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

In .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=your_db_name
DB_USERNAME=your_db_user_name
DB_PASSWORD=your_db_password
```

hope, this may work out. Thanks.